# Issue with using regular expressions in tidyr

Tags: r, tidyr

Using data is a question just asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963431/reformat-data-tables-based-on-row-names-to-generate-new-columns-in-r), I wanted to spread the data using `tidyr` using `extract()`.

```
df<-read.table(header=T,text=
                "id m1      m2     m3
 P001.st   60.00   2.0     1
 P003.nd   14.30   2.077   1
 P003.rt   29.60   2.077   1
 P006.st   10.30   2.077   1
 P006.nd   79.30   2.077   1
 P008.nd    9.16   2.077   1")

df %>% 
  extract(id, c("id2", "var"), c("(P00.)\\.(..)"))
```

Which was based off an answer from hadley [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925556/gather-multiple-sets-of-columns-with-tidyr).

But I get the error:

```
Error in drop && length(x) == 1L : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
```

I don't normally use regular expressions, but would like to start to, so if someone could help me understand where I'm failing, it'd be much appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: I cannot replicate your error. I use dplyr 0.4.1.9000...It works fine.

Comment: Yes, getting rid of the c() made it work. Can you explain why @hadley's response in my linked stackoverflow response includes the c()?

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier with `separate`? e.g. `df %>% separate(id, c("id2", "var"), "\\.")`

Comment: For this particular example, sure. But using extract() with regular expressions can give greater flexibility down the road.

Comment: @MihaTrošt, `extract` is from tidyr, not dplyr. @Andrew: I can't reproduce the error with tidyr 0.2.0. What version are you running?

Comment: I'm using `tidyr_0.2.0`. The issue seems to be that I included the `c()` outside of the regular expression. Did you exclude this, or is it working with the `c()` included?

Comment: I used `extract(df, id, c("id2", "var"), c("(P00.)\\.(..)"))` and `extract(df, id, c("id2", "var"), "(P00.)\\.(..)")` (and the separate version above) and they all produce the same output without error message. Maybe restart R with a new session?

Comment: @docendodiscimus Just kidding. Now it's working just fine with the c(). I guess I didn't have `tidyr` loaded and it was using a different `extract` or something...I have no idea

Comment: Ok that's good. I'm voting to close the question then as "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error".

Answer (score 3):

Probably your script is loading also `magrittr` **after** loading `tidyr` but you forgot to mention.

So you are actually referencing `magrittr::extract` instead of `tidyr::extract`.

You can either

1. Load `magrittr` *before* loading `tidyr`; or
2. Reference `tidyr::extract` explicitly.

Both must work.

Comment: Just to complement, `magrittr::extract` is just an alias defined there for `[`

Comment: Also, I incurred in this error and thought I could share its solution